# Mouse cursor over multiple elements with the parent element keeping its new background color

Tags: jquery, html

I am fairly new to JQuery and I was wondering how can I place the mouse over a main category `Cat` that has sub categories `Sub Cat` and have the main category display a different background color even when I place the mouse cursor over the sub categories until I select another main category `Cat` only.

Thanks for the help.

HTML

```
    <ol id="cat">
        <li><a title="" href="">Cat 1</a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a title="" href="">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
                    <li><a title="" href="">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
                    <li><a title="" href="">Sub Cat 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a title="" href="">Cat 2</a></li>
        <li><a title="" href="">Cat 3</a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a title="" href="">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
                    <li><a title="" href="">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
                    <li><a title="" href="">Sub Cat 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a title="" href="">Cat 4</a></li>
    </ol>
```

JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cat li a:parent').hover(
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery, when you can use CSS?

Example:

```
 ol>li a{background:#DDD;} //define the original bg color for the parent
 ol>li ul{display:none;} //hide your subs
 ol>li:hover a{background:#CCC;} //your parent category changes color
 ol>li:hover ul{display:block;background:red;} //your subcategories are shown
```

I forgot how people that post questions on here prefer to have people write the entire code for them.  Unfortunately I can't, but this should put you on your way:

http://jsfiddle.net/zL9me2um/

Comment: This actually did not work thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yea well maybe you're doing it wrong. Why don't you set up a fiddle and I'll show you

Comment: All the categories stay the same color even on hover. and the main cat should change to a different color when hover over the its sub cat

Comment: Like I said the the sub categories should be a different color then the main category a simple cut past would do I dont have a jsfiddle account.

Comment: Then add the color here in CSS: `ol>li:hover ul{display:block;}`  Do you know how to use CSS?

Comment: You don't need an account for jsfiddle

Comment: I suggest you learn CSS if you don't know how to use it. IT will save you and us the time. Good luck

Comment: If i remember my CSS correctly a child element cant change the color of its parent element.

Comment: You can in CSS3, but its not fully supported in all browsers.  If I understand, you want to show the subs and change the color of the parent at the same time to one color right? Or you want each subcategory to change the color of the parent category?

Comment: I want my main category to change to a different color and stay that same color when the mouse is hovering over the box as well as the links the sub categories are contained in.

Comment: Well then you may want to go learn CSS and learn how to change the color of a hovered object. Because the example I gave, does exactly that.

Comment: You may want to brush up on your CSS because it dosen't do what I explained to you.

Comment: You may want to brush up on your english because it does what you asked in your question.

Comment: You may want to get glasses and learn how to read instead shouting insults.